# How do I search and retrieve a file's contents in one HTTP request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, url, request

I'm using Springboot, and want to fetch a YAML file from a number of BitBucket folders. The file naming is inconsistent between folders, but I can identify the file I want using a `GET` request with the query `?extension=yaml`.

However, what is returned is the metadata for the files that satisfy that query (just one file, in this case). I can then send a second request to specified file path and grab the resource itself - but is there a way of fetching the file via a search query rather than a specific file path? **In short - can I do this in one request, not two?**

My request uses the Springboot `RestTemplate` object, specifically its `.getForObject` method, and my request is in the following format:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repository}/{path-to-containing-folder}/?extension=yaml
```

...or will this be something that depends on the API in question?

Comment: Yes it would depend on the API, and a "proper" RESTful API wouldn't do that with one call (due to the REST ["spec"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)). So in theory it's possible, if you write the server. In practice it's not possible, because you didn't write the server.

Comment: @Kayaman - that makes sense, thanks! Two calls it is...